# Rails app testing with RSpec and Capybara. I get Error Capybara::ElementNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara

> _customers_table.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= customer.name %></td>
        <td><%= customer.phone_number %></td>
        <td><%= customer.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to customer.status.humanize, toggle_status_customer_path(customer), class: "move-to-black" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', customer %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', customer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> creating_customer_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "creating new customer", type: :feature do
  let(:customer) { customer = FactoryBot.create(:customer) }

  it 'should create new customer' do
    visit '/customers/new'
    fill_in 'Name', with: customer.name
    fill_in 'Phone number', with: customer.phone_number
    click_button 'Create Customer'
    expect(page).to have_content "#{customer.name}"
  end

  it 'should change customer status' do
    visit '/'
    click_on customer.status.humanize
    expect(customer).to have_status "move_to_white_list"
  end
end
```

The first example 'should create new customer' pass but I get error with the second one 'should change customer status'

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link or button "Move to black list"
```

The element exists and you can see it on the image.
I would really appreciate if someone can help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN31m.png)

> I changed the second example, now it works.This is my mistake I didn’t
>   explain it well, the “black list” table is on a different view and
>   when the status changes, it moves to another page so actualy it's not
>   possible to find it there.

```
    require 'rails_helper'

describe "creating new customer", type: :feature do
  let!(:customer) { customer = FactoryBot.create(:customer) }

  it 'should create new customer' do
    visit '/customers/new'
    fill_in 'Name', with: customer.name
    fill_in 'Phone number', with: customer.phone_number
    click_button 'Create Customer'
    expect(page).to have_content "#{customer.name}"
  end

  it 'should change customer status' do
    visit '/customers'
    click_on customer.status.humanize
    expect(page).to have_content "Customer #{customer.name} moved to black list"

    visit '/black_list'
    expect(customer.reload.status).to eq "move_to_white_list"
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you maybe tried `click_link` instead of `click_on` in your test?

Comment: I can't see your "create customer" element there

Comment: @Clepsyd `click_on` is an alias for `click_link_or_button` so using just `click_link` wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of issues here. Firstly you're going to the page before the customer instance has been created, which means it won't be shown on the page. This is because `let` lazily evaluates - see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let - and will only create the customer the first time customer is called in the test.

```
visit '/' # <= no customer instance exists here
click_on customer.status.humanize # <= customer instance actually created here
```

You can fix that by using the non lazily evaluated version `let!` which will always create a customer instance, or by calling `customer` before calling `visit`

Secondly, your test is modifying the customer instance in the DB, but never reloading the instance you have in memory (so the new status would never be seen)

```
expect(customer.reload).to have_status "move_to_white_list"
```

Thirdly, If you're using a driver that supports asynchronous behavior (any driver other than rack-test) there is no guarantee any side effects caused by the action methods (`click_on`, etc) will have completed before the method call returns. That means your expectation will most likely get called before the customer instances status has changed. To fix that the `have_status` matcher would need to be written to have retrying behavior (like all the Capybara provided matchers have) and to have the reloading behavior in the matcher too. This is a major reason why it's generally not a good idea to be verifying DB changes in system/feature tests, and instead stick to verifying changes in the UI.

Comment: I found a solution, it is in the question changes. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and your time.

Comment: @MichaMichael  you’re welcome - don’t forget to accept the answer (the check mark) if it helped you so your question gets marked as answered